# How to count the number of members of different departments after executing a JOIN between two tables?

Tags: sql, join, count

I have a table `Emp` and another table `Dept`

This is table Emp

[image]

This is table Dept

[image]

The query I have to execute is to display the average salary (i.e., sal) for all departments (i.e. DeptName) with more than 5 working people. So we'll have to do a `JOIN` or something and match the `DeptID` here with the `DeptID` there etc.

This is really confusing and I don't understand how to go about it.

Comment: Why `Dept_ID` is `NULL` in the `Emp` table, I think it should not be because every employee belongs to department ? Query will ignore `NULL Dept_ID` employees.

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by with having clause query for that.

group by `Dept_id` and check count using having clause.

```
SELECT
  SUM(E.Sal) / COUNT(E.Dept_id) AS Avg_Sal,
  E.Dept_Id
FROM EMP E
JOIN Dept D
  ON D.DeptId = E.Dept_Id
GROUP BY E.DeptId
HAVING COUNT(E.Dept_Id) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
DeptName,
AVG(sal) as averageSalary,
Count(EmpId) as NumberofEE
FROM Emp e
/*Left Join Because there are Nulls in the Dept_Id each Emp should belong to 
1 dept*/
LEFT JOIN Dept d on e.Dept_Id = d.DeptId

GROUP BY 
DeptName

Having Count(EmpId)> 5
```

This will give you the average salary (i.e., sal) for all departments (i.e. DeptName) with more than 5 working people

If i'm right with your requirement.